# Can I be notified when my paypal authorization is set to expire?

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

We have an online store built in Magento and in the Paypal config it is set to "Authorization" and not "Sale." We have to have it that way because we don't always have the part in stock but need to order it. Is there a way to be notified when the paypal authorization is about to expire? Its not in Paypals admin nor is it in Magentos admin for the notification.